# Custom ASPNetMembership FailureInformation always null, OnValidatingPassword issue

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, asp.net-membership, asp.net-4.0

As stated here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.onvalidatingpassword.aspx

"When the ValidatingPassword event has completed, the properties of the ValidatePasswordEventArgs object supplied as the e parameter can be examined to determine whether the current action should be canceled and if a particular Exception, stored in the FailureInformation property, should be thrown."

Here is some details/code which really shows why FailureInformation could be  null http://forums.asp.net/t/991002.aspx

According with my Membership settings i should get an exception that password does not match password security conditions, but it is not happened.

Then i did try to debug System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll(in .NET 4.0 System.Web.Security located here) Framework Code to see whats really happens there, but i cant step into this assembly, may be because of this `[TypeForwardedFrom("System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral,   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")] 
    public abstract class MembershipProvider : ProviderBase`

Easily i may step into any another .NET 4.0 assembly, but in this one not. I did check, symbols for System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll loaded.

Now i have only one idea how ti fix it - to override method OnValidatingPassword(ValidatePasswordEventArgs e).

Thats my story.

May be some one may help:

1) Any ideas why OnValidatingPassword not working?

2) Any ideas how to step into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have read this http://forums.asp.net/t/991002.aspx one more time. Here is my solution

```
    //Override OnValidatingPassword
    protected override void OnValidatingPassword(ValidatePasswordEventArgs args)
    {
        //Any logic to process password validation conditions
        //e.g:
        if (args.Password.Length < MinRequiredPasswordLength)
            args.FailureInformation = new ArgumentException(String.Format("Password is too short, min password length {0}", MinRequiredPasswordLength.ToString()));

        if (args.UserName == args.Password)
            args.FailureInformation = new ArgumentException(String.Format("Password should not be equal to username"));

        //Also here could be any logic to throw an exception if needed
        //e.g:
        if (args.FailureInformation != null)
            throw args.FailureInformation;

        //Calling base
        base.OnValidatingPassword(args);

        if (args.Cancel)
        {
            if (args.FailureInformation == null)
                args.FailureInformation = new ArgumentException(String.Format("Custom Password Validation Failure for password '{0}'", args.Password));

            throw args.FailureInformation;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am confused about this -- what does the base method actually do if you have to do comparisons on the MinRequiredPassword length and other configuration items?

Comment: @pc1oad1etter my complete implementation contains logic which checking password not contains user name, the base implementation does not do that, and probably you right, call base is not required if i check all the rest config values myself.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to override the OnValidatingPassword method but as the documentation say you need to handle ValidatingPassword event. Check [MembershipValidatePasswordEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipvalidatepasswordeventhandler.aspx).

Use the .NET Reflector and inspect the ChangePassword method of SqlMembershipProvider class. You will see the SqlMembershipProvider doesn't have any handler registered for ValidatingPassword event.

So what I am thinking is in your custom membership provider's OnInit you register to Membership.ValidatingPassword and in the handler you do your coding. The sample example in the link above.

Hope I am not misunderstanding your question.

Comment: First time I did exact the same, this code won't validate password. If password is wring 'this.OnValidatingPassword(e)' didn't add any information about that to 'e.FailureInformation' or set 'e.Cancel' to true. Thats why i mentioned that looks like i need to override it and finally what i did.

Comment: Please don't show dissembled proprietary code on a public forum like SO, since people reading this are not allowed to contribute to ie. Mono mono-project.com/Contributing

Comment: Pauli Østerø: Thanks for pointing that out. Never thought source code that has been made public can have viewing restrictions. I have edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to indicate you're using a Custom Membership provider?  So I assume you're implmenting MembershipProvider directly?

`class MyMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider{...}`

In that case, OnValidatingPassword is never automatically called...you have to call it yourself.

**So, basically I'm confused.  Could you please clarify your setup? Are you using a default membership provider or a custom one?  If custom, which class are you inheriting from?**

As for looking at the code, you can use Reflector to do it.

Comment: I am inheriting from MembershipProvider. I did call it my self, but it is didn't do anything helpful.