# Does the default Membership Provider's OnValidatingPassword have to be overridden in custom implementations?

Tags: .net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, custom-membershipprovider

I am working to implement a custom Membership Provider for my .net application.  I have set up the configuration for a minimum number of characters and non-alphanumeric characters, but it seems to let passwords through anyway, even when they break the rules.

OnValidatingPassword is a virtual method.  The [example from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) does not override the method.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611720/custom-aspnetmembership-failureinformation-always-null-onvalidatingpassword-issu) grapples with the same problem, but the author gave up on getting the answer to his question and simply overrode the function.  This [answer states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611720/custom-aspnetmembership-failureinformation-always-null-onvalidatingpassword-issu/4619031#4619031) that one does not have to override the function to have it work.

Does the base function not do anything?  When I override OnValidatePassword, and simply call the base class, my function gets hit, but it never rejects my too-simple passwords.

Code sample (with a custom CreateUser function)

```
protected override void OnValidatingPassword(ValidatePasswordEventArgs e)
        {                        
             base.OnValidatingPassword(e);
        }
        //
        // MembershipProvider.CreateUser
        //
        public MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string globalIdentifier, string firstName, string lastName, 
            string birthDate, object providerUserKey, out MembershipCreateStatus status)
        {
            ValidatePasswordEventArgs args = new ValidatePasswordEventArgs(username, password, true);
            OnValidatingPassword(args);

            if (args.Cancel)
            {
                status = MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidPassword;
                return null;
            }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation for [MembershipProvider.OnValidatingPassword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.onvalidatingpassword.aspx) only states that that it raises the `ValidatingPassword` event if a handler is registered, not that it actually validates the password.

Looking at the method in Reflector confirms this:

```
protected virtual void OnValidatingPassword(ValidatePasswordEventArgs e)
{
    if (this._EventHandler != null)
    {
        this._EventHandler(this, e);
    }
}
```

It is confusing, but I believe the intent is that this provides a hook for external logic to participate in password validation;  A custom provider would still need to write its own validation logic.

If you take a look at the source code for the SQL Membership Provider (download the [Provider Toolkit Samples](http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/b/3/ab3c284b-dc9a-473d-b7e3-33bacfcc8e98/ProviderToolkitSamples.msi)), you'll see that it includes logic to validate the password, and also calls `OnValidatingPassword`.  The following code is from the `CreateUser` method:

```
if( password.Length < MinRequiredPasswordLength )
{
    status = MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidPassword;
    return null;
}

int count = 0;

for( int i = 0; i < password.Length; i++ )
{
    if( !char.IsLetterOrDigit( password, i ) )
    {
        count++;
    }
}

if( count < MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters )
{
    status = MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidPassword;
    return null;
}

if( PasswordStrengthRegularExpression.Length > 0 )
{
    if( !Regex.IsMatch( password, PasswordStrengthRegularExpression ) )
    {
        status = MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidPassword;
        return null;
    }
}

ValidatePasswordEventArgs e = new ValidatePasswordEventArgs( username, password, true );
OnValidatingPassword( e );

if( e.Cancel )
{
    status = MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidPassword;
    return null;
}
```

---

### *Edit*

I think part of the confusion is based on the name of `OnValidatingPassword`, and that it seems to imply that it is handling password validation, rather than raising an event to let other code validate the password.  For what it's worth, I understand the confusion - it would probably be clearer if the method had been named `RaiseValidatingPasswordEvent`.

In any case, you can check the [Event Design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229011.aspx) guidelines for .NET 4.  About halfway down the page, you'll find this:

> **Do use a protected virtual method to raise each event.**
>
> The name of the protected virtual method should be the
>   same as the event name prefixed with On. For example, the protected
>   virtual method for an event named "TimeChanged" is named
>   "OnTimeChanged".

Comment: I may not have made it clear, but when I do override the base method, my method does get called.  So it's not a question of whether or not the method gets called -- it just seems to *not do anything*

Comment: Right - it doesn't do anything besides raise the `ValidatingPassword` event.  `OnValidatingPassword` does not do any validation itself.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  How can OnValidatingEvent be responsible for raising the ValidatingPassword event -- isn't it responding *to* the ValidatingPassword event?

Comment: It's common to create virtual methods to raise events named `OnSomeEvent(EventArgs args)` and then actually raise the event there.  See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724085/events-naming-convention-and-style/724114#724114).  So `OnValidatingEvent` isn't responding to the event - it's raising it.

Comment: @pc1oad1etter, please see my edit - I added a better source of information regarding the name of `OnValidatingPassword`.  HTH.

Comment: Thanks for your time.  Let me see if I can summarize your position -- the base class does do something (it raises the event.)  However, the implementer is required to handle even cases such as minimum password length on his own.  Additionally, the Microsoft example is either incomplete or in error, as is the answer I linked to that says one does not need to override the method.  Accurate?

Comment: @pc1oad1etter yes, that is accurate. I believe that example is incorrect - nowhere do they have code that actually validates the password, and we know that `MembershipProvider` does not do it. The answer you linked to is correct - you can override `OnValidatingPassword` and put your validation logic there, but you don't *have* to - see my next comment.

Comment: Other ways you could do this instead of overriding `OnValidatingPassword`:  (1) attach a handler to the `ValidatingPassword` event with the validation logic and let the base `MembershipProvider.OnValidatingPassword` call it, (2) put the validation logic in the `CreateUser` method (as the `SqlMembershipProvider` does), or (3) put validation logic in a separate method in your provider and call that method from `CreateUser`, `ChangePassword`, and wherever else you might need to validate a password.

Comment: I'm marking this as correct, but I'm pretty surprised to hear that the linked resources have such misinformation.